# Facebook comments - fb.api comments: only returns first 25 comments

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I use the code below to catch a new facebook comment on my blog, and make some actions (push data into a db and thank user):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(a) {       
        FB.api('comments', {'ids': a.href}, function(res) {
        var ufb_message = '';
        var ufb_from = '';
        var ufb_name = '';
        var ufb_jump = false;
        var testJSON = res[a.href].comments.data;
        var i=0;
        while(i < testJSON.length) {
        try{
        var tempJSON = testJSON[i].comments.data.pop();
        if (testJSON[i].comments.count > 0 && tempJSON.id == a.commentID) {
        ufb_message = tempJSON.message;
        ufb_from = tempJSON.from['id'];
        ufb_name = tempJSON.from['name'];
        ufb_time = tempJSON.created_time;
        i=testJSON.length;
        ufb_jump = true;
        }
        } catch(e) {}       
        i++;
        }
        if(!ufb_jump) {
        var data = res[a.href].comments.data.pop();
        ufb_message = data.message;
        ufb_from = data.from.id;
        ufb_name = data.from.name;
        }
        alert('Thanks for your comment!' + ufb_name);
        <?php
        [...] php code to execute [...]
        ?>
        });
        });
        </script>
```

If comments are < 25 all is ok.
From the 26th comment data returned are always about the 25th comment.

I suppose it's because of the default limit=25 in json

p.e.:
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.isocial.it/aggiornamento-ios-7-beta-iphone

returns the first page with 25 comments.

when I have more comments, data catch from my code always refer to the 25th comment.

many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your data, there should be a "paging" paramater, this will return more of your comments. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/